# Keep shared values after refresh or reload in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-applications

I have a `data.service.ts` file which stores the variable which is shared among many components in my Angular project.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class myService {
  public sharedData:string;

  constructor(){
    this.sharedData = "String from myService";
  }

  setData (data) {
    this.sharedData = data;
  }
  getData () {
    return this.sharedData;
  }
}
```

And created the class (`myService`) in 'providers' only once on the `app.module.ts` file and imported the injectable file: `data.service.ts`
And I am using the get and set methods in components and this works perfectly fine. But when I reload or refresh the page, the value is gone. I have seen solutions suggesting the use of `localStorage` but is there another way to keep the values persistent even after refresh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you reload the page you restart the Angular application. So it contains only initial data. Everything you want to save you have to save either on the back-end or in `localStorage`.